# Alignment remote databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, wcf

I have this scenario:

I have a software that uses the SQLServer database.
I have to create a new Web application (Asp.net) that uses the same database.

The Software and SQLServer are on Server A
The application with its IIS Web Server are on Server B

I then this situation:

Software + SqlServer <---> Internet <---> Web Application Web Server + IIS + SQLServer
Server A Server B

Is there a safe way to align two databases through the internet? The changes must be done in real time on both.
I have thought of WCF services...I consider dangerous to expose the database.
Any idea?Eventually, Sql server has the tools to align the database remotely?

Comment: eh...you could use transactional/merge replication pushing both ways. This is not trivial but would be more reliable than having your app manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , through the SQL server replication you can achieve the same. The Sql Server will synchronize the databases whenever the changes occurs. Please refer to the documentation of replication to choose an appropriate replication model and set it properly within your network.

Comment: Hi I'm now reading the documentation about SQL server replication, I need to know how do I manage concurrency in the same operations, it is possible?

Comment: You can try updatable subscription. In this form the triggers are added to the publisher and fire immediately to send the change to the subscribers using Microsoft Distributed Transaction Controller (MSDTC). The changes are performed in a transaction.I think thats what you are looking for. All or No changes at all? Is my answer the best answer :)